# IO.open says a command is not recognized

Tags: ruby, windows

The ruby version is

```
c:\temp> C:\opt\sensu\embedded\bin\ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13) [i386-mingw32]
```

I have this ruby script

```
cmd = "c:\\windows\\system32\\pslist.exe | findstr notepad"
output = IO.popen(cmd).readline
...
```

It throws the following error

```
'c:\windows\system32\pslist.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However if I run `pslist` or `c:\windows\system32\pslist.exe` in command prompt, it runs OK and produces result as expected.

Why it does not work in ruby?

**EDIT**

Apparently, if I call "`tasklist`", it works. But the alternative command "`pslist`" simply failed.

Comment: Is it a 64-bit Windows installation? What's the output of `ruby -v`?

Comment: Why is `pslist.exe` even in the system32 folder? Can it be reproduced with `C:\tools\pslist.exe`, for example?

Comment: are you able to run `cmd.exe` with `IO.popen`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong well, then are you able to run `pslist.exe` with `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ `cmd.exe /C pslist` works fine if i run it in a command prompt. Same problem if run from the ruby script

Comment: @AnthonyKong well, interesting. Cound to try the same 2 steps with direct path to `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a [64-bit (WOW64) redirection](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/02c7df62-0e29-46e1-9b57-b9fdf76ca091/cant-run-local-program) problem.

Try something like

```
cmd = "#{File.join(ENV['windir'], 'sysnative', 'pslist.exe'} |  findstr notepad"
```

and see if that works.